# Which blade should I use on a Silverline Adjustable Hole Cutter with Cowl?

Tags: drywall, tools

I just bought this hole cutter to make some large holes in a plaster board ceiling.    It comes with two sets of blades but no instructions!  So which type blade should I use for plaster board?

The blades are claimed to be TCT blades, HSS blades on the box, but they are not labeled, so it is not even clear which blade is which.

[image: Picture of hole cutter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCT = Tungsten Carbide Tipped
HSS = High Strength Steel

The tungsten/carbide tipped would probably be best reserved when you're cutting metal or something harder; the high strength steel blades should be sufficient for most applications.

Comment: Looking at the blade how do I tell between the two

Comment: Not sure. Either would be fine to cut into plaster or wood with though.